# Centering a button with Foundation

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

Im trying to center a button using foundation, here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-6 small-centered columns">
        <a href="#" class="button">Default Button</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

After reading the docs, I believe the above should work, am I missing something?

Comment: try lists:<ul><li> for button group...http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/1115-centering-a-button-group

Comment: But it's not a button gorup.

Comment: ok..have you tried text-center?

Comment: It's not text... it's a button

Answer (score 8):

Your code center the column only. All content inside the column will be left-aligned by default as expected.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|           |<a>                    |           |  
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

If you want to center the content inside the column, you have to add `text-center` in your CSS class:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-6 small-centered text-center columns">
        <a href="#" class="button">Default Button</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the result would be:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|           |          <a>          |           |  
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
        <div class="cell small-4">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="cell small-4"><a href="#" class="button">Default Button</a></div>
        <div class="cell small-4">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```